# Why not executed liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I execute changeset:

```
     <changeSet id = "1" author = "yu">
        <preConditions onFail = "MARK_RAN">
           <not>
              <indexExists schemaName = "myschema" indexName = "my_table_idx" />
           </ not>
        </ preConditions> 
          <createIndex tableName = "my_table" indexName = "my_table_idx">
                  <column name = "id_1c"> </ column>
                  <column name = "program_id"> </ column>
          </ createIndex>
     </ changeSet>
```

I get the error: **ERROR: relation "my_table_idx" already exists**

It turns out that does not work preConditions. Why?

Comment: Your `createIndex` will create the index in the schema of `my_table`. You don't specify the schema name for the `createIndex` tag, so maybe you have _another_  `my_table_idx` in the default schema, but not in `myschema`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , I added schema but it did not help

Comment: As long as you do have the schema specified on the `createIndex`, then a_horse_with_no_name is right: it should work. So I would suggest generating the SQL and looking at that to see if it gives any clues. Post it here if you like. Also it would be interesting to see the complete output you're getting when you run the changeset.